# Parametrized class issue

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I´m getting a weird behaviour with parametrized types. 
I´ve a class A that extends the class B. A has an inner class A1 that extends the class Predicate.
The code looks like this:

```
public abstract class A<T> extends B<T> {
    public T uniqueResult (String param, Object value) {
        A1 filter = new A1();
        filter.setParam(param);
        filter.setValue(value);
        return container.query(filter).next();
    }
    public class A1 extends Predicate<T> {
        public boolean match (T bean) {
            Object result = BeanUtils.getPropertyValue(bean, fieldName);
            return result == null ? null : result.equals(value);
        }  
    }
}
```

Finally the class D extends A and uses the uniqueResult method:

```
public class D extends A<MyVO> {
    public MyVO findById (BigDecimal id) {
        return uniqueResult("id", id);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the match method (inside A1) receives BigDecimal instead of MyVO.
If I override the uniqueResult method in D it works fine but I don´t get why this happens.

The overrided uniqueResult looks like this:

```
public MyVO uniqueResult (final String fieldName, final Object value) {
    return container().query(
        new Predicate<MyVO>() {
            private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;
            public boolean match(MyVO bean) {
                Object result = BeanUtils.getPropertyValue(bean, fieldName);
                return result == null ? null : result.equals(value);
            }
        }
    ).next();
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: `Finally the class ,` - where's the class? It looks like you're missing the question as well...

Comment: Sorry, It seems that a part was missed.

Comment: Based on how you're defining `D`, `uniqueResult` should be returning type `MyVO` - all the other things (B, A1) don't impact the return type of `uniqueResult`.

Comment: "The problem is that the match method (inside A1) receives BigDecimal instead of MyVO" - Ofcourse, because you're passing it a `BigDecimal` in `D.findById`. What did you expect? "If I override the uniqueResult method in D it works fine" - What do you mean? Show some code that demonstrates this.

Comment: Mmm, no. The match method is called by the predicate. As it´s defined, match should receive an object of type as defined in the parametrization of Predicate , that is MyVO not BigDecimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was at Java Generics type erasure. 
The API I am using (that contains the class Predicate) has an issue when creating a predicate parametrized like Predicate. Fortunately, it provides a constructor that receives the concrete class to be matched as argument. It isn´t elegant but it works.

The code is like this:

The method uniqueResult in A:

```
protected T uniqueResult (final String fieldName, final Object value) {
    return container().query(
        new Predicate<T>(getPredicateClass()) {
            private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;
            public boolean match(T bean) {
                Object result = BeanUtils.getPropertyValue(bean, fieldName);
                return result == null ? null : result.equals(value);
            }
        }
    ).next();
}
```

Added

```
protected abstract Class<T> getPredicateClass();
```

Finally in D:

```
protected Class<MyVO> getPredicateClass() {
    return MyVO.class;
}
```

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Behavior can't be affected by generics at all. It's compile-time feature and the generics info is (effectively) lost after compilation. So the problem is somewhere else, IMO.

Btw why don't you introduce just Predicate getFilter() and override override just that. Would get more readable.